# Github Scheduled Reminders - Some Slack Mentions Aren't Linked

Tags: github, slack

We have setup scheduled reminders for one of our teams in GH.  When the reminders are displayed in Slack, some of the users' accounts are not linked properly.  For those users, it just shows their GH username unlinked.  Everyone else (probably 80% or better of our users) has a proper @ mention instead of their GH username.  I've looked at profiles for unlinked users in both systems and cannot determine a clear root cause.

Has anyone else seen this, any possible solutions?

EDIT: The plot thickens. I'm seeing the SAME USER in the SAME REMINDER both be @ mentioned correctly/linked and incorrectly/unlinked.  There's a pattern for the affected users:

- On the line that prints the PR #, Title, and Owner, the affected users' github username appears unlinked.
- On the line that prints the days stale/days old/waiting on list, SOME of the affected users' will be correctly @ mentioned and some will not.

Maddening.

Comment: How are you getting the slack @ mentions?  Are they coming from github commit messages?  Do all of your users have their github usernames set in a github field in their profile or how are you mapping the user accounts from github to slack?

Comment: @JosephIshak they're coming in via Scheduled Reminders as configured in Github.  See: https://docs.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-organizations-and-teams/managing-scheduled-reminders-for-your-team

I've looked at profiles in both systems and don't see a consistent pattern of "mapping" for those mentions that work vs those that do not.

Comment: Do they have special characters in their usernames? like an `@`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the slack users where this doesn't work, have you tried having them unsubscribe from github using a `/github unsubscribe` followed by a `/github subscribe` command again to get github to refresh their slack account information?

I am not sure if the application you are using is a separate application or if it is part of the github to slack integration.  If it is, it talks about how your accounts are not linked until this step is performed.

I came across this article here:  https://github.com/integrations/slack#configuration

```
Subscribing and Unsubscribing
At this point, your Slack and GitHub user accounts are not linked. To link the two accounts, authenticate to GitHub using a /github slash command, /github signin.

The /github slash command also accepts a subscribe argument that you can use to subscribe to an Organization or Repository's activity /github subscribe <organization>/<repository>.

unfurl_code

If you originally gave the app access to "All repositories" and you've created a new private repository on GitHub after installing the GitHub integration for Slack, the /github subscribe command will work automatically on your new repository. If you installed the app on a subset of repositories, the app will prompt you to install it on the new repository.

The /github slash command also supports unsubscribe. To unsubscribe to notifications from a repository, use /github unsubscribe <organization>/<repository>
```

Comment: I don't believe we've ever established user-level subscriptions.  We push the scheduled reminders to specific channels that have the Github app as a channel member.  It's possible that some people have done this on their own.  Will investigate.  Thanks for the lead.

Comment: I don't see a way for it to look up usernames, otherwise, so I would think the messages would behave more like "@here" or "@channel".  Alternatively, you could put the author's slack user id  (not the display name) in the pull request but that would be a lot more cumbersome.  I think you would also have to unsubscribe/resubscribe if you change either your github or slack usernames such as when someone gets married and changes their name.

Comment: This ends up fixing it, for a while.  Unclear why it breaks again for some users, but seems like the right answer.  Thank you.